# Ajax request is retrieving an empy array in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, request

I have a "form" with this code:

```
<div class="form-wrap" id="contact-form">
    <div class="form-innerwrap">
        <div class="text-input">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
            <label for="name"><?= CONTACT_FORM_NAME ?></label>
        </div>

        <div class="text-input">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required />
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        </div>

        <div class="text-input">
            <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" required />
            <label for="name"><?= CONTACT ?></label>
        </div>

        <div class="text-input text-textarea">
            <textarea type="info" id="info" name="info">

             </textarea>
            <label for="email"><?= CONTACT_FORM_MENSSAGE ?></label>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="lang" id="lang" value="<?= $_SESSION['language'] ?>">
        <div class="form-button">
            <button type="submit" class="btn contacts-button btn-gowe" id="btn-info" data-btnhover="<?= CONTACT_FORM_BTN ?>"> <span><?= CONTACT_FORM_BTN ?></span> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a ajax request to sent the input values to php:

```
$("#btn-info").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var contact = $("#contact").val();
        var info = $("#info").val();
        var lang = $("#lang").val();
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email='+ email +'&contact='+contact+'&info='+info+'&lang='+lang;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/sendEmail.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                var result = result.split("||");
                if (result[0]== "true"){
                    $("#contact-modal").show();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

However when I make a var_dump of $REQUEST the return is an empty array.

Can anyone help me with this problem?
I had already spent several hours to try to understand what is wrong in my code.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: $REQUEST is not a thing, use $_POST

Comment: Do a var_dump on $_POST, what you are trying is actually $_REQUEST

Comment: also build an object to post, making your own string without encoding will likly break.

Comment: Right. If you really have to build a string, you need to use `encodeURICompoment()` around all the variables to encode them properly.